# jquery attach a hover event handler to a path within an embedded svg file

Tags: jquery, event-handling, svg, embed

I'm trying to attach a hover event handler to a path within an embedded svg using jquery.

The embed code in the html looks like this:

```
<embed id="theSVG" src="thesvg.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="2000" height="1280" />
```

I can make it work if I do not embed the svg, but put it into the html inline, then use the following javascript, linked to from the html file:

```
$('path').hover(
function () {
//do something
};
}, 
function () {
//do something else
};
}
);
```

But I do not know how to reference the path within the embedded svg via jquery.

Thanks,

Fb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you would need svg plugin for jQuery to access svg embedded code. [Here's the example](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#dom) of attaching events to paths in svg using [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html).

In general it looks like this:

```
var svg = $('#svg_container').svg('get');
$("#path_id", svg.root()).bind('click', function() {
    alert('path clicked');
})
```

Comment: Thanks WTK. I can see that what you're saying is what I need, I just can't understand how to implement it at the moment. I've probably got a little bit ahead of my understanding of javascript.